# Findall equivalent for xpath , Lxml

Tags: python, xml, xpath, lxml, findall

I am extracting text with respect to tags and I need to get them in a list form w.r.t p tags. I have this xpath expression as:

```
 find =  etree.XPath("//w:p//.//*[local-name() = 'ins']//text()" ,namespaces={'w':"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main"})
```

And i want to use it in a `findall` expression. I tried:

```
inserted_list_1=[]
for p in lxml_tree.findall('.//{' + w + '}p'):
    inserted_list_1.append([t.text for t in p.findall('.//{' + w + '}ins')])
```

but all this returns is a list full of `None` values whilst the former xpath works perfectly.
I think there's some intermediate path missing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot use that expression with `findall()`; the `findall()` method deliberately keeps compatibility with the [limited ElementTree API XPath support](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#elementtree-xpath).

Use the [`xpath()` method](http://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html#the-xpath-method) instead:

```
for p in lxml_tree.xpath('.//w:p', namespaces={'w': w}):
```

and just use namespace prefixes for much more readable queries.

If you just wanted to extract all contained text, you can use:

```
[t for t in p.xpath('../w:p//w:ins//text()',namespaces={'w': w})]
```

Comment: and what should I use for text?? t.text doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @Swordy: are you certain there is text directly contained in those `ins` elements?

Comment: @MartijnPieters No, there isn't. Most likely that's a dialect of OOXML, where text is inside `w:ins/w:r/w:t`. So, `w:ins//text()` works fine. +1.